# Rake database migrate failing with "undefined method `double`"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rake, rails-migrations

I've defined a scaffold with some of the sqlite columns having type `double`.  When I run `rake db:migrate`, it gives the following error:

```
undefined method `double' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition:>
```

Is there another way to specify a `double` that Rails will understand? Should I be using a `float` here?

Here's the scaffold command:

```
rails generate scaffold shop name:string latitude:double
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `float` instead of `double`. Take a look [here](http://overooped.com/post/100354794/ruby-script-generate-scaffold-types).